# Extension, get value of TCA select

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I created a new extension with the extension_builder and added a select-field:

```
'selectlist' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:my_test/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mytest_domain_model_test.selectlist',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'items' => array(
            array('LLL:EXT:my_test/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tx_mytest_domain_model_test.selectlist.item1', 0),
            array('LLL:EXT:my_test/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tx_mytest_domain_model_test.selectlist.item2', 1),
        ),
        'size' => 1,
        'maxitems' => 1,
        'eval' => ''
    ),
),
```

In the template I access this field with:

```
<td><f:link.action action="show" arguments="{test : test}"> {test.selectlist}</f:link.action></td>
```

The problem is that `test.selectlist` is only the key of the select-item. But what I need is the value (in my case the translated value from locallang.xlf).

I have not found any documentation about how to access the value in the template.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe dublicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381917/in-a-typo3-6-1-fluid-template-how-to-parse-values-from-a-select-box But I want to keep the question open. The linked question is 3 years old and maybe something changed in that time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I can use a work around.

```
array('LLL:EXT:my_test/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tx_mytest_domain_model_test.selectlist.item1', 1),
array('LLL:EXT:my_test/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tx_mytest_domain_model_test.selectlist.item2', 2),
```

and

```
<f:translate key="tx_joyatest_domain_model_test.selectlist.item{test.selectlist}" />
```

this works, cause the translation key can be identified by the select-item-key.

Comment: Actually this is not a work around but the solution. :)

Comment: @AndrásOttó we can argue about if this is really a solution. A solution would be if I have direct access to the item-value ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try biesior's [answer for "TYPO3 TCA type select in FLUID?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35562339/4942215). That technique may be helpful to you, or give you an idea.

Comment: thanks, biesiors solution is very similar to my workaround I found.